What would be the most trustable vagrant box for Ubuntu 24.04 and newer releases
After Canonical drop support for Vagrant boxes I'm finding it difficult to know what Ubuntu 24.04 box to choose. There are several, but which one to pick ?
What would be the nearest to an "official" ubuntu 24.04 vagrant box ? What criteria are people using to choose ?

I had a same question.  Looking at number of download, bento/ubuntu-24.04 seems quite popular.  It is generated by Bento project.
